# android get Drawable image after picasso loaded

Tags: android, callback, drawable, target, picasso

I am using Picasso library to load image from url. The code I used is below.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);
```

What I wanna do is to get the image that loaded from url. I used

```
Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
```

However, this will always return placeholder image instead of the image load from url. Do you guys have any idea? How should I access the drawable image that it's just loaded from url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because the image is loading asynchronously.  You need to get the drawable when it is finished loading into the view:

```
   Target target = new Target() {
          @Override
          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
              imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
          }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
   };

   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
```

Comment: How can I use loadBitmap()? I need to call Picasso twice?

Comment: No that is just a void method you would call to load the image.  You don't need it. (see updated answer)

Comment: this is useless, `fit, centercrop` won't work, what the point in using Picasso then?? you can get drawable with normal Picasso callback: `into(targetImageView, new Callback() {
   @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                 targetImageView.getDrawable();
            }`

Answer (score 2):

```
        mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPicasso = Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext());
                mPicasso.load(IMAGE_URL)
                        .resize(mImageView.getWidth(), mImageView.getHeight())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(mImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                Drawable drawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                                // ...
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You may want to add some explanation why this code solves the problem.