# save to a Drawable from Piccaso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm making an app that in many other functions, pulls images via URL and then it shows them in a PDF file. I did it on the hard way downloading them and using an asyncTask to handle all the process, but I heard that piccasso does this work better and cleaner so I decided to give it a try. 
So I want to put the image loaded with piccaso within a Drawable so let's say I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Drawable drawable=Picasso.get().load("URL");
```

which of course is ridiculous and it's impossible, so I'm wondering if there is a way I can pull the image
with picasso and then transform it to a Drawable so I can then draw it on the PDF file that I need to generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you:

```
Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
      }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
 };

Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
```

Or, just look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799983/11162243

Comment: thank you, in case that i don't save it first on a imageView, how can i retrieve it directly to Drawable?

Comment: nevermind, in that case just use the Bitmap parameter, thanks a lot!